# Alternative to Ntop on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, network-monitoring, ntop

ntop is a great tool for recording network throughput statistics for FreeBSD based firewalls. The statistics can be displayed as graphs using a web browser. Ntop, however, has the limitation that it does not allow you to filter the throughput per host; you can only filter per interface or per some hardcoded protocol and port numbers.

Is there a similar tool which is more flexible? In particular, I am looking for the possibility to filter by host.

I already have examined and excluded the following tools: Cacti, IPAudit, IPTraf, MRTG, Zabbix. Reason for exclusion: missing functionality or no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a web broswer [darkstat](http://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) might meet your needs. It's ridiculously easy to setup and use. I just added the following one-liner to my `rc.local`.

> `/usr/local/sbin/darkstat --syslog --no-macs -i sis0 -b 192.168.0.1 -p 80 -f "not
>    arp"`

---

[image: darkstat host table]